# Importing an XML into MySQL, Can't get all children tags

Tags: php, mysql, xml, arrays, csv

First let me begin with what we're doing here:
We're pulling an XML file from 1 server and placing it into another server which is where the php code is sitting too.
Then some of the XML data needs to be imported into a local MySQL db.
The XML is a copy of orders for an online store. Some orders contain multiple items the person ordered, some don't if they only ordered one item.

So for the XML example we have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmldata>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>2119</OrderID>
    <AddressValidated>Y</AddressValidated>
    <Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>2.0000</Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>
    <AuthHash>d995fd9424fb99e80f58841a0ff2340f</AuthHash>
    <AVS />
    <BillingAddress1>122 27th West</BillingAddress1>
    <BillingAddress2>Floor 11</BillingAddress2>
    <BillingCity>New York</BillingCity>
    <BillingCompanyName />
    <BillingCountry>United States</BillingCountry>
    <BillingFaxNumber />
    <BillingFirstName>Dan</BillingFirstName>
    <BillingLastName>Test</BillingLastName>
    <BillingPhoneNumber>646456777</BillingPhoneNumber>
    <BillingPostalCode>10001</BillingPostalCode>
    <BillingState>NY</BillingState>
    <CardHoldersName />
    <CC_Last4 />
    <CreditCardAuthorizationDate>3/30/2012 11:52:00 AM</CreditCardAuthorizationDate>
    <CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>MANUAL</CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>
    <CreditCardTransactionID />
    <Customer_IPAddress>184.56.49.45</Customer_IPAddress>
    <CustomerID>19</CustomerID>
    <CVV2_Response />
    <GiftWrapNote />
    <IsAGift>N</IsAGift>
    <LastModBy>7</LastModBy>
    <LastModified>3/30/2012 1:39:00 PM</LastModified>
    <Locked>Y</Locked>
    <Order_Comments>Test sale - Don't process
Ignore statuses on this order</Order_Comments>
    <Order_Entry_System>PHONE</Order_Entry_System>
    <OrderDate>3/30/2012 11:01:00 AM</OrderDate>
    <OrderNotes />
    <OrderStatus>Ready to Ship</OrderStatus>
    <PaymentAmount>8.1600</PaymentAmount>
    <PaymentMethodID>17</PaymentMethodID>
    <PONum />
    <Processed_AutoEvents>Y</Processed_AutoEvents>
    <SalesRep_CustomerID>7</SalesRep_CustomerID>
    <SalesTax1>0.1700</SalesTax1>
    <SalesTax2>0.0000</SalesTax2>
    <SalesTax3>0.0000</SalesTax3>
    <SalesTaxRate>0</SalesTaxRate>
    <SalesTaxRate1>0.08375</SalesTaxRate1>
    <SalesTaxRate2>0</SalesTaxRate2>
    <SalesTaxRate3>0</SalesTaxRate3>
    <ShipAddress1>123 27th West</ShipAddress1>
    <ShipAddress2>Floor 1</ShipAddress2>
    <ShipCity>New York</ShipCity>
    <ShipCompanyName />
    <ShipCountry>United States</ShipCountry>
    <ShipFaxNumber />
    <ShipFirstName>Dan</ShipFirstName>
    <ShipLastName>Test</ShipLastName>
    <ShipPhoneNumber>646782342</ShipPhoneNumber>
    <Shipping_Locked>Y</Shipping_Locked>
    <ShippingMethodID>1</ShippingMethodID>
    <ShipPostalCode>10001</ShipPostalCode>
    <ShipResidential>Y</ShipResidential>
    <ShipState>NY</ShipState>
    <Stock_Priority>3</Stock_Priority>
    <Tax1_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
    <Tax1_Title>Tax (8.375%)</Tax1_Title>
    <Tax2_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
    <Tax2_IncludePrevious>0</Tax2_IncludePrevious>
    <Tax2_Title />
    <Tax3_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
    <Tax3_IncludePrevious>0</Tax3_IncludePrevious>
    <Tax3_Title />
    <Total_Payment_Authorized>0.0000</Total_Payment_Authorized>
    <Total_Payment_Received>7.0700</Total_Payment_Received>
    <TotalShippingCost>5.9900</TotalShippingCost>
    <VendorID>0</VendorID>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>3374</OrderDetailID>
      <AutoDropShip>Y</AutoDropShip>
      <FreeShippingItem>Y</FreeShippingItem>
      <GiftTrakNumber>0</GiftTrakNumber>
      <GiftWrap />
      <GiftWrapCost>0.0000</GiftWrapCost>
      <GiftWrapNote />
      <IsKitID />
      <KitID />
      <Locked>Y</Locked>
      <OnOrder_Qty>0</OnOrder_Qty>
      <OptionIDs />
      <Options />
      <OrderID>2119</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>test-product</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>39200</ProductID>
      <ProductName>Test Product 1</ProductName>
      <ProductNote />
      <ProductPrice>1.0000</ProductPrice>
      <ProductWeight>1</ProductWeight>
      <QtyOnBackOrder>0</QtyOnBackOrder>
      <QtyOnHold>1</QtyOnHold>
      <QtyShipped>0</QtyShipped>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TaxableProduct>Y</TaxableProduct>
      <TotalPrice>1.0000</TotalPrice>
      <Vendor_Price>0.0000</Vendor_Price>
      <Warehouses />
    </OrderDetails>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>3386</OrderDetailID>
      <AutoDropShip />
      <FreeShippingItem>Y</FreeShippingItem>
      <GiftTrakNumber>0</GiftTrakNumber>
      <GiftWrap />
      <GiftWrapCost>0.0000</GiftWrapCost>
      <GiftWrapNote />
      <Locked>Y</Locked>
      <OnOrder_Qty>0</OnOrder_Qty>
      <Options />
      <OrderID>2119</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>test-product</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>39200</ProductID>
      <ProductName>Test Product 2</ProductName>
      <ProductNote />
      <ProductPrice>1.0000</ProductPrice>
      <ProductWeight>1</ProductWeight>
      <QtyOnBackOrder>0</QtyOnBackOrder>
      <QtyOnHold>1</QtyOnHold>
      <QtyShipped>0</QtyShipped>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TaxableProduct>Y</TaxableProduct>
      <TotalPrice>1.0000</TotalPrice>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>2141</OrderID>
    <AddressValidated>Y</AddressValidated>
    <Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>1.0000</Affiliate_Commissionable_Value>
    <AuthHash>14cca8be8db44ca9943f0a6cbf592c83</AuthHash>
    <AVS />
    <BillingAddress1>122 27th West2</BillingAddress1>
    <BillingAddress2 />
    <BillingCity>New York2</BillingCity>
    <BillingCompanyName />
    <BillingCountry>United States</BillingCountry>
    <BillingFaxNumber />
    <BillingFirstName>Dan2</BillingFirstName>
    <BillingLastName>Test2</BillingLastName>
    <BillingPhoneNumber>646346322</BillingPhoneNumber>
    <BillingPostalCode>10002</BillingPostalCode>
    <BillingState>NY</BillingState>
    <CardHoldersName />
    <CC_Last4 />
    <CreditCardAuthorizationDate>3/30/2012 3:33:00 PM</CreditCardAuthorizationDate>
    <CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>MANUAL</CreditCardAuthorizationNumber>
    <CreditCardTransactionID />
    <Customer_IPAddress>56.75.23.34</Customer_IPAddress>
    <CustomerID>19</CustomerID>
    <CVV2_Response />
    <GiftWrapNote />
    <IsAGift>N</IsAGift>
    <LastModBy>7</LastModBy>
    <LastModified>3/30/2012 3:33:00 PM</LastModified>
    <Locked>Y</Locked>
    <Order_Comments>Test sale #2, don't process, ignore status.</Order_Comments>
    <Order_Entry_System>PHONE</Order_Entry_System>
    <OrderDate>3/30/2012 3:32:00 PM</OrderDate>
    <OrderNotes />
    <OrderStatus>Ready to Ship</OrderStatus>
    <PaymentAmount>7.0700</PaymentAmount>
    <PaymentMethodID>17</PaymentMethodID>
    <PONum />
    <Processed_AutoEvents>Y</Processed_AutoEvents>
    <SalesRep_CustomerID>7</SalesRep_CustomerID>
    <SalesTax1>0.0800</SalesTax1>
    <SalesTax2>0.0000</SalesTax2>
    <SalesTax3>0.0000</SalesTax3>
    <SalesTaxRate>0</SalesTaxRate>
    <SalesTaxRate1>0.08375</SalesTaxRate1>
    <SalesTaxRate2>0</SalesTaxRate2>
    <SalesTaxRate3>0</SalesTaxRate3>
    <ShipAddress1>123 27th West2</ShipAddress1>
    <ShipAddress2 />
    <ShipCity>New York2</ShipCity>
    <ShipCompanyName />
    <ShipCountry>United States</ShipCountry>
    <ShipFaxNumber />
    <ShipFirstName>Dan2</ShipFirstName>
    <ShipLastName>Test2</ShipLastName>
    <ShipPhoneNumber>6461234789</ShipPhoneNumber>
    <Shipping_Locked>Y</Shipping_Locked>
    <ShippingMethodID>1</ShippingMethodID>
    <ShipPostalCode>10002</ShipPostalCode>
    <ShipResidential>Y</ShipResidential>
    <ShipState>NY</ShipState>
    <Stock_Priority>3</Stock_Priority>
    <Tax1_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
    <Tax1_Title>Tax (8.375%)</Tax1_Title>
    <Tax2_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
    <Tax2_IncludePrevious>0</Tax2_IncludePrevious>
    <Tax2_Title />
    <Tax3_IgnoreNoTaxRules />
    <Tax3_IncludePrevious>0</Tax3_IncludePrevious>
    <Tax3_Title />
    <Total_Payment_Authorized>0.0000</Total_Payment_Authorized>
    <Total_Payment_Received>7.0700</Total_Payment_Received>
    <TotalShippingCost>5.9900</TotalShippingCost>
    <VendorID>0</VendorID>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>3404</OrderDetailID>
      <AutoDropShip>Y</AutoDropShip>
      <FreeShippingItem>Y</FreeShippingItem>
      <GiftTrakNumber>0</GiftTrakNumber>
      <GiftWrap />
      <GiftWrapCost>0.0000</GiftWrapCost>
      <GiftWrapNote />
      <IsKitID />
      <KitID />
      <Locked>Y</Locked>
      <OnOrder_Qty>0</OnOrder_Qty>
      <OptionIDs />
      <Options />
      <OrderID>2141</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>test-product</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>39200</ProductID>
      <ProductName>Test Product</ProductName>
      <ProductNote />
      <ProductPrice>1.0000</ProductPrice>
      <ProductWeight>1</ProductWeight>
      <QtyOnBackOrder>0</QtyOnBackOrder>
      <QtyOnHold>1</QtyOnHold>
      <QtyShipped>0</QtyShipped>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TaxableProduct>Y</TaxableProduct>
      <TotalPrice>1.0000</TotalPrice>
      <Vendor_Price>0.0000</Vendor_Price>
      <Warehouses />
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</xmldata>
```

As you can see the first order contains two `<OrderDetails>` while the second only contains one.

I have created four functions so far that get me very close.

```
processxml();
processxmldetails();
vl_readytoship_download();
csvimport();
```

The first imports the .xml file from the other server so we can get to work.

```
function vl_readytoship_download() {
echo "Downloading Ready To Ship Orders...<br>";
$ch = curl_init("http://www.link.to/vl_rts.xml");
$fh = fopen("vl_rts.xml", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

The second function converts the XML to CSV so we can better read it for importing (This step may not be required or the best method, which is why I'm here, however, it does work.)

```
function processxml() {
vl_readytoship_download();
echo "Processing Ready To Ship Orders...<br>";
$filexml='vl_rts.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('vl_rts.csv', 'w');
foreach ($xml->Orders as $Orders) {
    fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($Orders),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
}
```

Now I didn't at first notice that the CSV doesn't contain the data from any `<OrderDetails>` tags. I only realized it when I began work in the importing to MySQL function.

So instead of going backwards, I forged ahead to get the `<Order>` data imported at least:

```
function csvimport() { 
if(!file_exists("vl_rts.csv")) { echo "WARNING! CSV Not Found!<br>"; exit; }
$row = 0;
$mycsvfile = array();
if (($handle = fopen("vl_rts.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        }
        $mycsvfile[] = $data; //add the row to the main array.
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo "<br>Reading Rows:<br>";
//[row][column] so [1][$csvrow] = 2nd row, first column since 0=1
$csvrow = 0;
while ($mycsvfile[$csvrow][0] != $null) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from vtiger_purchaseorder WHERE orderid=" . $mycsvfile[$csvrow][0]) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{
//if row exists
$csvrow++;
echo "Row exists, changing rows...<br>";
echo "DO SOMETHING HERE, ANYTHING BUT THIS<br>"; //This is a "todo" spot for later
}
else //if row doesn't exist
{

$currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
$orderid = $mycsvfile[$csvrow][0];
$subject = "Uploading..."; //This is set to Uploading... now, in another function we'll come back change the subject to the name of the item sold.
$quoteid = $mycsvfile[$csvrow][0];
if ($mycsvfile[$csvrow][72] == 0) {
$vendorid = "1500"; //right now, new orders go into a temp vendor of 1500, then we'll change it based on the product ordered to see which vendor it should be assigned to.
echo "Vendor is " . $vendorid . "<br>";
$shipcity = "Shipcity"; This info is in <OrderDetails> which we don't have yet.

//This other database is vtiger, which has a lot of different area where it needs to store data, so here we insert it in a way vtiger can accept it.
$query1 = "SELECT * from vtiger_crmentity";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO vtiger_crmentity (smcreatorid,smownerid,modifiedby,setype,orderid) VALUES('1','1','1','PurchaseOrder','" . $orderid . "')";

$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$crmid = mysql_insert_id();

$query3 = "SELECT * from vtiger_purchaseorder";
$query4 = "INSERT INTO vtiger_purchaseorder (purchaseorderid,subject,quoteid,vendorid,duedate,orderid) VALUES(" . $crmid . ",'" . $subject . "','" . $quoteid . "','" . $vendorid . "','" . $currentdate . "','" . $orderid . "')";

$query5 = "SELECT * from vtiger_poshipads";
$query6 = "INSERT INTO vtiger_poshipads (poshipaddressid,ship_city,orderid) VALUES(" . $crmid . ",'" . $shipcity . "','" . $orderid . "')";

echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
$result4 = mysql_query($query4);
echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
$result5 = mysql_query($query5);
echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
$result6 = mysql_query($query6);
echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
echo "CRMID " . $crmid . "<br>";

$csvrow++;
echo "Order doesn't exist, inserting order number " . $orderid . " from CSV row " . $csvrow . "<br>";
//CHANGE ORDER FROM READY TO SHIP TO PENDING SHIPMENT ON OTHER SITE (to do)


}
} 
}
echo "Import Complete.<br>";

}
```

Now quick recap. So we've pulled the .XML file from the other server. We have taken everything (except all children) from `<Orders>` and inserted it into a CSV and now we have taken the CSV data and inserted it into the MySQL DB to make a new purchase order.

The new purchase order is there, but it's missing data from `<OrderDetails>` tags.

I have tried to place all `<OrderDetails>` data into an array, but I only get the first two tags which are in the first `<Order>`.

Ideally, I would love to extract all `<OrderDetails>` tags and insert them into another CSV file. From there I'll pull it and insert it using the same method as above. I've tried this, but the CSV is off, the rows aren't lining up and I still only get the first 2 tags, not all of them.

I'm open to anything, so let me know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should process the XML directly. You are losing the hierarchy of the data by trying to convert it to a CSV file.

You can use SimpleXML to read all the data. It will look like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
foreach ($xml->Orders as $order) {
  $order_id = $order->OrderId;
  $order_status = $order->OrderStatus;

  // Here we have a single order
  // You can insert this order into the database

  foreach ($order->OrderDetails as $order_details) {
    $order_detail_id = $order_details->OrderDetailID;
    $product_id = $order_details->ProductID;

    // Here we have a single order detail that belongs to $order_id
    // You can insert this order detail into the database
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay this is looking good but the problem is me, I'm not 100% getting it. Thanks so much for helping. Okay so once I have it parsed using this method which puts each tag's data under OrderDetails into $order_details. Now I see for each tag, we're also putting the an ID number or each ID number into $order_details_id. How can I call on say the first OrderDetails OrderDetailID tag, check the number and do some stuff, then move on to the next OrderDetails? Thanks so much for helping and sorry I'm not fully getting it yet.

Comment: I edit my answer to make it easier to see how you can get the data and insert it into the database.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is getting me on the right track. Can you show me how to call on the first OrderDetails and then the second etc.. and keep in mind the first order has two OrderDetails, the second has one. Which is why I need to call on each OrderDetails, one at a time, checking the OrderDetailsID and then inserting it accordingly, then moving on to the next OrderDetails.